# Flink: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type TypeInformation

Tags: scala, apache-flink, implicit-conversion

I write a Flink(1.11.2) program using Scala(2.12.13), a few code piece as below:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala._
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
...
val table: Table = tableEnv.from("packets")
val dataStream = table.select($"userId", $"num").toAppendStream[(String, Long)]
```

I got a compile error:
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[(String, Long)]
val dataStream = packets.select($"userId", $"cloudStore").toAppendStream[(String, Long)]

I have to explicitly add TypeInformation to avoid this error.

```
val dataStream = table.select($"userId", $"num")
  .toAppendStream[(String, Long)](TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint[(String, Long)] {}))
```

And now I have got a dataStream of type DataStream[(String, Long)], but when I call map on it:

```
dataStream.map { item =>
  print(item._1, item._2)
}
```

still get error: No implicit arguments of type: TypeInformation[Unit]. Another time I have to add it to make it work:

```
dataStream.map { item =>
  print(item._1, item._2)
}(TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint[Unit] {}))
```

I'm confused. So anyone would like give a explanation? Thank you guys.

Comment: Problem solved - delete 'import org.apache.flink.api.scala._'

Comment: If you find the solution to your own problem, it is OK to post that as an Answer. This makes it easier for people to find rather than having to look at the comments.